# Getting different results for LASSO using cv.glmnet and caret package in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, glmnet

I saw few posts here regarding my issue. I went through with those but still i couldnt figure out what i did wrong.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I fitted a LASSO logistic regression model using glmnet package and caret package (which is a wrapper for glmnet package) and i am getting different results .

Here is my code :

Using glment package ,

```
require(ISLR)
require(glmnet)
y <- Smarket$Direction
x <- model.matrix(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Volume, Smarket)[, -1]

lasso.mod <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha=1,family="binomial",nfolds = 5, type.measure="class",
                       lambda = seq(0.001,0.1,by = 0.001))

> lasso.mod$lambda.min
[1] 0.1
```

using caret package ,

```
require(caret)
set.seed(123)
fitControl1 <- trainControl(method = "cv",number = 5,savePredictions = T,returnResamp="all")
modelFitlassocvintm1 <- train(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Volume, data=Smarket, 
                              method = "glmnet", 
                              trControl = fitControl1,

                              tuneGrid=expand.grid(
                                .alpha=1,
                                .lambda=seq(0.001,0.1,by = 0.001)),

                              family="binomial")

modelFitlassocvintm1$bestTune

   alpha lambda
26     1  0.026
```

as you can see, based on 5-fold cross validation i am getting different values for the tuning parameter `lambda`. can any one help me to figure out what did i do wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to do with the way the two functions are dividing the dataset for the n fold cross-validation. Even the slightest difference in the folds will cause the optimum parameter to vary.

this plot shows that both models are about the same:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x = lasso.mod$lambda,y = 1-lasso.mod$cvm))+
  geom_point(aes(x = modelFitlassocvintm1$results$lambda,y = modelFitlassocvintm1$results$Accuracy),color = "red")+
  labs(x = "lambda",
       y = "accuracy")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyway Leave one out cross validation (LOOCV) should give the identical answers. isnt it ? I tried to do LOOCV using cv.glmnet by giving nfolds=nrow(Smarket). But it is not working